# ngBind span with calculation function not appearing in IE

Tags: javascript, angularjs, internet-explorer, html

I am using angularjs to build out a rating template.  It works great in all browsers except for any IE browser.

```
<span class="rating">
    <span class="ratingfill" style="padding-left: {{r.Rating / 5 * 100}}%"></span>
    <img src="/images/rating_content.png" alt="">
</span>
```

The issue is that IE does not calulate the padding.  In fact it appears in the in the IE console inspector as

```
<span class="ratingfill"/>
```

and that is it.  Any suggestions would be appreciated...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems IE doesn't like the change of style properties this way.

Try this:

```
<span class="ratingfill" ng-style="{'padding-left': (r.Rating / 5 * 100) + '%' }"></span>
```

[here is a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L4pqc/)